# Never executes the code. Java

Tags: java

My issue is when I run the code in eclipse it just never seems to do anything at the bottom. The other day I made some almost identical programs and they worked fine. The only thing I can assume is going on is it never gets the input from scanner so it never prints the line so the program just keeps on running.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class testrun {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String name;
        Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);
        name = get.nextLine();
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you type something and press Enter?

Comment: You have literally just made me feel like the biggest idiot ever :D, That is the issue, in the other programmes I was always putting something like, System.out.print("Type...: "); but in this I wasn't and I just totally forgot, Thank you.

Comment: LoL - no worries mate!

Comment: mark his answer as accepted, to help others see the solution

Comment: Just waiting for the timer to pass then I will :D

Comment: Didn't even know such thing exists :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may need to type something and hit that ENTER key. The Scanner's nextLine() is waiting for input.

:)

It happens to us all.

Answer (score 1):

The program works good and asks for input.

Keep some sop to print some helping statements and make it user friendly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Testrun {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String name;
        System.out.println("Please Enter : ");
        Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);
        name = get.nextLine();
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more of a comment I'm afraid, in light of the recent solution.